# My ASP.NET Core HttpClientFactory message handler is not catching an exception further in the pipeline

Tags: asp.net, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to add an `HttpMessageHandler` (`DelegatingHandler`) to an `HttpClientFactory` pipeline in ASP.NET Core in order capture an exception that occurs further down the pipeline:

**HttpAuthorizationExceptionHandler.cs**

```cs
class HttpAuthorizationExceptionHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    public HttpAuthorizationExceptionHandler()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Created HttpAuthorizationExceptionHandler");
    }
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("HttpAuthorizationExceptionHandler.SendAsync");
        try
        {
            return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
        catch (AccessTokenNotAvailableException e)
        {
            e.Redirect();
            return Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```cs
//...
builder.Services.AddScoped<HttpAuthorizationExceptionHandler>();
builder.Services.AddRefitClient<IUserProfileApi<AuthenticationProfile>>()
        .ConfigureHttpClient(httpClientConfig)
          .AddHttpMessageHandler<HttpAuthorizationExceptionHandler>()
          .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>(); // This throws AccessTokenNotAvailableException
//...
```

In the above example, I added `HttpAuthorizationExceptionHandler` *before* `BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler` in the pipeline since intended to capture an exception that `BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler` may throw. I also tried putting it *after*, but it still didn't work.

During an HTTP request, I can see my log messages logged so my handler is clearly being executed, but it's not capturing the exception and I get `Unhandled Exception` error for `AccessTokenNotAvailableException`. This leads me to believe I ordered it wrong in the pipeline, but I have moved it before and after the message handler which is throwing the exception with no luck.

What am I doing wrong?